# Slow network performance when I open files from a local network server

Tags: networking, hardware

When I try  to open a file from a network share, the file takes much longer than expected to open. It will eventuallly open, but is very slow I have restared both the server and my local computer,  checked the network card , updated firmware and drivers for network cards, but the problem is still there, my pc is running windows 7 proffesional , and the network is running server 2008 enterprise. If I copy things over it works fine, is just when opening any type of file..

I have to mention that opening files from any other server in the network works fine, is just this one server ... Any ideas ? suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What changes did you make to the machine(s) before the error started occuring? My first guess would be anti-virus on your end-user machine. Some AV's go nuts when they have realtime scanning enabled when trying to access files via shares.

If you have AV on, I would try disabling it for testing purposes. If that helps, add a scanning exclusion to your shared drive.